# Project Euler #3 - Solution runs forever

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

First time I've ever encountered this problem. It feels like it will never end.

My approach:

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Euler3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long result = 0;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        long numberGiven = 600851475143L;
        TreeSet<Long> nums = new TreeSet<>();

        for (long i = 2L; i < numberGiven; i++) {
            if (numberGiven % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
                nums.add(i);
            }
        }

        result = nums.last();   

        System.out.print("Result: " + result +
            ".\nTime used for calculation in nanoseconds: " +
            (System.nanoTime() - startTime) + ".");
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        if (n <= 3) {
            return n == 1 ? false : true;
        } else if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            for (int i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6) {
                if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this works on smaller numbers, but as is probably intended doesn't seem effective on over 600 billion.
I'm wondering, without giving the answer away:

1. Is there some obvious alteration I could employ to reduce the
   running time/checks necessary?
2. Although it clearly doesn't work effectively here, is this approach
   otherwise acceptable or would someone who posted this challenge,
   even with a smaller number, be looking for something different?
3. I tried with integers the first time and got an overflow related error, is anything similar happening under the hood that would actually prevent this from terminating?

Comment: Use BigInteger instead of long?

Comment: `int i` should be `long i` in isPrime, but I suspect your program will still take a while with that fix (instead of forever).

Comment: I wish you hadn't edited, I actually lol'd @ "a couple of years."

Comment: so, to put it in words, the "obvious alteration" is to divide out each factor as it is found, enumerated in ascending order, which makes *all* primality checks unnecessary. And enumerate potential factors not while `i < numberGiven`, but `i*i <= numberGiven`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *every* number you're checking that's a factor, you're doing an *internal* loop to figure out if it's a prime. That means your algorithm is effectively performing `n * m` operations.

You can instead use the following mathematical "trick", which I think is the same used by the UNIX `factor` program.

Since every number over one is either prime or a unique product of a set of primes (with potential duplicates in the set), we can just start dividing the number by the first prime two (actually reducing the number in the process) until that's no longer possible (i.e., it becomes odd). At that point, the reduced number will not have two or any multiples of two as a factor.

Then we do the same by continuously dividing by three until that's no longer possible.

Now you'd think that may be onerous but, because you've stripped out all the 'two' factors, the number cannot *possibly* be a multiple of four (or any other even number for that matter). So we detect that and move up to the next divisor of five and start dividing by that.

So the division operation are only done for prime divisors, speeding things up considerably. In addition, once the divisor gets above the square root of the (reduced) number, no more factors are possible, so we exit. In that case, the reduced number gives us the final (hence highest) prime factor.

For example, consider the number `924`:

```
Number  Divisor  Result
------  -------  ------
   924        2*    462
   462        2*    231
   231        2     not divisible, go to 3
   231        3*     77
    77        3     not divisible, go to 4
    77        4     not divisible, go to 5
    77        5     not divisible, go to 6
    77        6     not divisible, go to 7
    77        7*    11
    11*       7     stop since 7 * 7 > 11
```

So the prime factors of `924` are `{2, 2, 3, 7, 11}`.

---

Now I urge you to try that algorithm on your own before looking below since the entire *point* of Euler is to test your *own* abilities. I simply provide the solution for completeness:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        long number = 600851475143L;

        // Start with a divisor of two,
        // continue until over sqrt(number).

        long divisor = 2L;
        while (divisor * divisor <= number) {
            if ((number % divisor) == 0) {
                // If factor, output then reduce number.

                System.out.println(divisor);
                number = number / divisor;
            } else {
                // Otherwise, move to next divisor.

                divisor++;
            }
        }

        // Final number is final divisor.

        System.out.println(number);

        System.out.print("Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: " +
                (System.nanoTime() - startTime) + ".");
    }
}
```

That gives you the four prime factors in about five *thousandths* of a second (on my box, anyway):

```
71
839
1471
6857
Time used for calculation in nanoseconds: 458826.
```

Comment: Only every number which is a factor of `600851475143L` (which makes this a *lot* faster than I first thought it was too, but still rather slow).

Comment: @immibis: no, not so, the whole thing runs sub-second under Eclipse Luna.

Comment: @immibis: if you mean "which code runs sub-second, I meant my code. Or your code as well, once you follow my advice :-)

Comment: This answer is good enough for the problem,but I think you can improve this further by only dividing for prime numbers, and you can keep dividing `testval` with `i` until `i` no longer divides `testval`

Comment: Okay, I understand, you meant OP wasn't running the internal loop except for the factors. I'll update the anser.

Comment: One more think you are missing, which is you are not checking for this case : for example 15 = 3*5, I believe your answer will only print 3!

Comment: You're absolutely right, @Pham, I didn't take that into account. The updates should fix that.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, my mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

The program can be simple like this, which runs under a second:

```
long val = 600851475143L;
long ans = 0;
for(long i = 2; i*i <= val; i++){
    if(val % i == 0){
       ans = i;
       while(val % i == 0)//This step will make sure that i is prime
           val /= i;
    }
}
if(val != 1){//If val is not 1, so val is a prime
   ans = val > ans ? val : ans;
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer is 6857, and it is correct answer :)

Notice that we only check for all `i` values which `i*i` smaller than `val`.